# Pass appendTo dynamic rows value to bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using `appendTo` to add dynamic rows. What I want to happen is that if I will click one of the `td` *(not including the remove button)*, It will open a bootstrap modal window and get the value of other `td` of its belonging row. here's the image.

[image]

[image]

Here's my code adding dynamically that I want to get the value of `td` and pass it to bootstrap modal.

```
function AddOrder(new_code, new_name, new_qtty, new_cost) {    
    var rows = "";  
    var code = new_code;
    var name = new_name;
    var cost = new_cost;
    var qtty = new_qtty;

    rows += 
        '<tr>"' + 
        '<td class="item_code" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">'+code+'</td>'+
        '<td class="item_name" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">'+name+'</td>'+       
        '<td class="item_qtty" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">'+qtty+'</td>'+ 
        '<td class="item_cost" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">'+cost+'</td>'+ 
        '<td>'+'<button class="btn remove-button">X</button>'+'</td>'+
        '</tr>';
    $(rows).appendTo("#dynamic_added tbody");
}
```

I tried putting putting `onclick` on `td` with `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal"` but only the modal is working not the function I'm using for example:

```
function GetData() {
    $('.item_code').click(function(){
        alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.item_code'));
    });
}
```

Comment: could you show me the html that has class `item_code`?

Comment: I am adding dynamically on `<table id="dynamic_added"><tbody></tbody></table>` the html is on the javascript code **rows**

Comment: on click you want get the next td row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved my own problem just a bootstrap modal call is all I am missing.
I addded a class `getdata` that I will call to my javascript function

```
function AddOrder(new_code, new_name, new_qtty, new_cost) {    
    var rows = "";  
    var code = new_code;
    var name = new_name;
    var cost = new_cost;
    var qtty = new_qtty;

    rows += 
        '<tr>"' + 
        '<td class="item_code getdata" onclick="GetData();">'+code+'</td>'+
        '<td class="item_name getdata" onclick="GetData();">'+name+'</td>'+       
        '<td class="item_qtty getdata" onclick="GetData();">'+qtty+'</td>'+ 
        '<td class="item_cost getdata" onclick="GetData();">'+cost+'</td>'+ 
        '<td>'+'<button class="btn remove-button">X</button>'+'</td>'+
        '</tr>';
    $(rows).appendTo("#dynamic_added tbody");
}
```

If I will click anywhere to the td except the button It will pop up the modal and pass the current data of that row.

```
function GetData() {
    $(document).on('click', '.getdata', function(){
        $('#mymodal').modal();
        var modal_code =$(this).closest('tr').find('.item_code').text();
        var modal_name =$(this).closest('tr').find('.item_name').text();
        var modal_qtty =$(this).closest('tr').find('.item_qtty').text();
        var modal_cost =$(this).closest('tr').find('.item_cost').text();

        var modal = $("#mymodal"); // this is the id of my modal 
        modal.find('.modal-body').text(modal_code + modal_name + modal_qtty + modal_cost);
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Do you want something like this:

```js
$('.item_code, .item_name, .item_qtty, .item_cost').click(function() {
  $('.modal-body').html($(this).closest('tr').html());
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="dynamic_added">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="item_code">code_1</td>
      <td class="item_name">name_1</td>
      <td class="item_qtty">qtt_1</td>
      <td class="item_cost">cost_1</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn remove-button">X</button>+</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item_code">code_2</td>
      <td class="item_name">name_2</td>
      <td class="item_qtty">qtt_2</td>
      <td class="item_cost">cost_2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn remove-button">X</button>+</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item_code">code_3</td>
      <td class="item_name">name_3</td>
      <td class="item_qtty">qtt_3</td>
      <td class="item_cost">cost_3</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn remove-button">X</button>+</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! but If I will click to other td of that row It should also get the value. In your code only the `td class="item_code"` will need to click to show those values.

Comment: @keisaac kk wait a sec

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the info. I already solved my problem. But If you have better solution I will be pleased.

Comment: @keisaac k, no problem!